# Must objects contain pointer members to be able to communicate with other objects?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I just started learning about design patterns, and I'm having trouble with some should-be-simple concepts. The concepts of some of these patterns make sense, but I'm struggling with how I should implement them in C++.

Let's saying I'm working on a problem that implements an observer problem. Let's assume there is only a single observer. That leaves two objects that need to communicate: the subject and the observer.

Conceptually, what this pattern is attempting to do is very simple to understand. However, I'm getting bogged down by questions like: where do they objects live? Must they both live within some container? How do they actually make requests from one another?

Regarding that last question, is it necessary for each object to a have a data member that references the other object? As in, must the subject contain a pointer to the observer, and must the observer contain a pointer to the subject?

So stepping away from the observer. If I have any two objects that are dependent to each other (uni-directionally or bi-directionally), is it necessary that each object have a pointer to its respective object?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical high-level run-time polymorphic implementation of the observer pattern has the *observable* object add a data member such as `std::vector<Observer*> observers_;`, and when something of interest happens the observable's member function iterates over that `observers_` calling some function through the `Observer*`s.  There's not necessarily any need for the `Observer`s to keep pointers/references to the `observable` object, but if it's useful they may do so, or the callbacks from the observable object might pass the `this` pointer or a reference to `*this` as a parameter.  Simpler observables might only support one `Observer*` instead of a container thereof.

For lower-level / performance-critical code - when it's practical to do so because you know the types involved at compile time - you may prefer to stipulate one or more observers at compile time - perhaps as template arguments.  That can allow the dispatch to be inlined and optimised, dead-code elimination to avoid calls to observers that do nothing etc..

> where do they objects live?

Anywhere that makes sense for the object's general function in the program.  For example, if a `Database_Server_Connection` was observable, it might let other parts of the program register interest in knowing when the connection's established asynchronously, when the connection's dropped, when async requests complete, when the database connection is closed by program code, when the database observable object's destructor runs.  The observers could be anywhere else in the program - they might be local objects in some function's scope, possibly in another thread, or they might be in or managed by smart pointers in a static or dynamically allocated container.

> Must they both live within some container?

Nope - as above.

> How do they actually make requests from one another?

Firstly, the code adding observers needs access to the observable object, and normally calls something like `observable.add_observer(this);` to register themselves, taking care to call `observable.remove_observer(this);` in their destructor so the observable never accidentally attempts a call into an already "destructed" object.  The callbacks then happen using the pointers stashed by `add_observer`.  As above, the callbacks may be passed pointers or references to the observable as arguments, the observers might have stashed away a pointer or reference earlier, or they might not even need one if all the information they need is passed to the callback and they don't need to mutate (call a non-`const` function on) the observable.

> So stepping away from the observer. If I have any two objects that are dependent to each other (uni-directionally or bi-directionally), is it necessary that each object have a pointer to its respective object?

It's often easiest, but sometimes some other communications mechanism may be used such as a queue or socket, in which case the communicating parties need some manner of pointer/reference/handle/id for that communications mechanism rather than pointers to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Another method you can use to make objects communicate is through an intermediate Queue object, or a socket, or other type of shared memory, so storing a pointer to the other object is not always necessary. In fact, to improve decoupling and write general code it is often better to use an event Queue or a Signal (see design of QT Libraries).

Don't take that as meaning that storing a pointer is wrong: it is often a good solution and avoid over-engineering which is expensive (in terms of money, time, and other computing resources).